# Android Studio two Errors

Tags: android, android-studio

I am new to Android Studio and can't seem to get my xml document to work, the KT file runs fine but I am not able to get my design view to display for me to add more textboxes/constraints. I have tried almost everything online to find a solution. Even the "Invalidate Cache/Restart" method I did. Still nothing. Now I have just errors on line 2 saying "element <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout must be declared" and I get another error for every TextView and EditText in the code. Please help me with what I may be doing wrong or even if its a simple thing.

[ManifestXML Lines 1-35](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L4qeX.png)

[ManifestXML Lines 35+](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fdhjz.png)

[MainActivity KT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sdn2a.png)

Comment: R u able build your project?

Comment: You made a pretty large mistake somewhere. You are supposed to put your layout files in the res > layout directory, not in the manifest file. The manifest is used to declare all the components of your app such as activities, broadcast receivers or permissions. Please read more about how to properly set up your manifest file here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro and the layout directory here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/layout-resource.html

Comment: No, I am not able to run it. I did part of it in class. Then saved it and did it on my laptop now.

Comment: I would suggest you to create a new project with a blank activity, then select Android from the [dropdown](https://realm.io/assets/img/docs/java/android-studio-project-view.png) where Project is selected. Now, with the new project and in Android mode, Your project structure will look like [this](https://www.tecmint.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/Main-App-View.png). The layout will be under res->layout and all layout comes here. The manifest.xml lists all your activities, services, permissions and app's special settings. It doesn't contain your layout. You'll learn more as you'll go.

Comment: Now, First, copy your layout from `manifest.xml` into your `activity_main.xml` which is under res-> layout. You can easily access it by clicking on `activity_main` in your class, click should be `ctrl+left mouse click`. With the new project, you can copy its manifest in your existing project's manifest.xml to correct it, don't forget to change your app name in it, other things will be same for a new project. This will fix the errors.

Answer (score 1):

The Mainfest file is not supposed work like that. Check this out to know more about the Manifest file: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro

All of your design part, like the layouts for every activity/fragment should mostly be inside the res>layout. Notice the setContentView in your MainActivity.kt, it includes the activity_main.xml file which is where you should put your design(XML) code.